# Jupyter Folder Full

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I recently downloaded Anaconda on my Windows and am trying to use the Jupyter notebook. However, when I open Jupyter, the it seems to be full of odd files.
[Odd Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1nAc.png)

I have tried to change the Jupyter home directory by changing the "Start in" in the Jupyter file but the home directory remained unchanged.
[Start in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgAPf.png)

There are two problems here. The first being that there are a large number of files and running the jupyter notebook makes my computer run slow. Second that when I try to add folders, I get the error that I do not have ownership to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix. I was previously running jupyter from the command prompt but running it through the anaconda navigator fixed it.